# Modifying array size at runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio, functor

I would like to know if there is a possibility of declaring the array size at runtime without using the new keyword.

```
struct myKernel
{
        uint8_t **var;
        myKernel(){}
        myKernel(const int number = 2)
        {
//I want to do something like
//var = new int*[number]; but not allocate it on the heap
           *var = a[number];
        }
        void operator()   
       {
        //do stuff here with the var array

       }
           
};
```

Comment: Well, if not on the heap, where else?

Comment: What do you mean by "static"? `var` isn't `static` here. Also, you should either use a `std::vector<uint8_t*>`, or manually allocate the memory on the heap with `var = new uint_8*[number]` (if by static you meant "on the stack", i'm not sure that VLAs are standard C++ precisely because of `std::vector` and i'm not sure it's a good idea either if `number` is big).

Comment: I though of allocating it on the stack, the solution would have been using templates, I did not thought of it at the beggining, so sorry I am still learning, I will post the code once I do it....thank you any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to be allocated at runtime (i.e based on runtime information) then you **have** to use heap-based allocation.

An alternative for your need could be to use a `std::vector` and to use `resize` but there would still be some dynamic allocation somewhere.

Comment: You can dynamically allocate to the stack.  That is what placement new is used for.

Comment: I may be wrong but this is not allocation anymore, it is construction from a raw memory, isn't it ? I mean there is no memory allocation if you use placement new this way.

Comment: I second Ninetainedo, (if i'm not mistaken) placement new only constructs the object, it assumes you have already allocated the memory at the address you're providing it. So you can use placement new on a stack address, but you'll have to allocate a (sometimes large) fixed-size well-aligned "buffer" beforehand.

Comment: What I am driving at though is that you don't have to use heap allocation.  You could have a pool of stack memory and then use it to create run time arrays.  It might not actually be called allocation but it is being done at runtime.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. Since I mentioned allocation, I do not consider placement new but you're totally right.

Comment: If you don't mind runtime allocation, you should definitely go with a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector)

Comment: @NathanOliver in that case you have just allocated a large array and are using a part of it